# Kill eval'ed process

Tags: bash, eval, kill

Take this script, merely as an example

```sh
#!/bin/sh

foo ()
{
  eval "$@"
}

touch bar
foo tail -f bar &
sleep 1
kill $!
```

In this example I would like to kill `tail`, however because `tail` was invoked as the result of an `eval`, it does not get killed. How could I kill `tail` without resorting to `pgrep`, `pkill`, etc?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? You're doing several useless things at once here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `exec` instead should work

```sh
#!/bin/sh

foo ()
{
  exec "$@"
}

touch bar
foo tail -f bar &
sleep 1
kill $!
```

If using with a pipe, you will need to do process substitution

```
foo tail -f bar > >(tee baz) &
```

[**related**](http://riccomini.name/posts/linux/2012-09-25-kill-subprocesses-linux-bash)

Answer (score 1):

It's because, when you `kill $!`, it's actually the subshell (foo &), that's getting killed with `SIGTERM`. You are not killing `tail` command.

As mentioned by svnpenn, either use `exec` so that the PID of subshell is inherited by `tail`.

Or use below code for tree traversing:

```
kill `ps -C tail --ppid $! -opid=`
```

It will list all tail process (`-C tail`) whose pid is $! (`--ppid $!`) & print only its PID `-opid=` & then kill that pid.